# How can I set a timeout in SNS publish method?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm using the AWS SNS service in my PHP application to send messages to a queue.

If internet connection is down, the application should keep running without writing the messages. But the method that publish messages on the queue has a very long timeout, it makes the application unusable without internet.

I didn't found any place in AWS SDK where I could set a smaller timeout.
Is there some way to do this?

Here is an example of the construct of the snsClient object.
I've edit the params to use http timeout as @Anthony Neace told, I also try to use request.options connect_timeout as I found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/configuration.html
I've changed the gateway of my PC to simulate when the internet is down and I got the exception **[curl] 28: Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds https://sns.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/**

```
    use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

    SnsClient::factory([
        'version'     => '...',
        'region'      => '...',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '...',
            'secret' => '...',
        ],
        'http' => [
            'timeout' => 5
        ],
        'request.options' => [
            'connect_timeout' => 5
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a timeout in your client's constructor. This will apply to all requests you make with that client, including SnsClient Publish.

Here's an example from the documentation, modified to use SnsClient:

```
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

// Timeout after 5 seconds.
$client = new SnsClient([
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http'    => [
        'timeout' => 5
    ]
]);
```

**Further Reading:**

- [AWS SDK for PHP - AWSClient Constructor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.AwsClient.html#___construct) (SnsClient inherits this constructor)
- [AWS SDK for PHP - SnsClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html)
- [AWS SDK for PHP - Client Configuration Options - Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#timeout)